# switch input place in the memory assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

I need to sort the array in one proc and than the smallest number should swap its place with the first number . than the second smaller number with the second number and so on... My just  wrote 00 00 00 00 in ds:0000

```
proc min
    push bx
    push ax
    mov si,bx 
    inc bx
    checkminnum: ; the outer loop for checking all the numbers
        mov al, [byte ptr si]
        cmp [byte ptr bx] , al
        jb smaller 
            mov si, bx; the offset of the smaller num is saved in si
        smaller:
        inc bx
        cmp [byte ptr bx], '$' ; check when the loop should end
    jne checkminnum
    pop ax
    pop bx
ret
endp min

proc swap
    push bx
    mov bx, offset array
    repos:
        call min
        mov al, [byte ptr bx]
        push ax
        mov al, [byte ptr si]
        mov [byte ptr bx], al
        pop ax
        mov [byte ptr si], al
        inc bx
        cmp [byte ptr bx], '$'
    jne repos
    pop bx
ret 
endp swap
```

Comment: _"My just wrote 00 00 00 00"_ For which input? Also, it seems to me like that `jb` in your `min` function should be `ja` (or switch the operand order for the `cmp`). Have you stepped through your code in a debugger to see what happens at each line?

Comment: Have you tried debugging it with single step to see where it goes different from what you're expecting?

Comment: @michael  , 5,7,8,0,12,6,$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *min* proc exhibits these two errors:

- You are using the opposite of the condition that you would need in order to find the minimum.
- Your code will, in its final iteration, treat the $-terminator as if it were an array element. You must check for the terminator **before** comparing with a following array element because said element might not exist.

What the code does is InsertionSort in the ascending order.

```
; IN (bx) OUT (al='$',si) MOD ()
proc min
    push bx
  SetMin:
    mov  si, bx    ; Position of minimum
  Cont:
    inc  bx
    mov  al, [bx]
    cmp  al, '$'
    je   Done
    cmp  al, [si]  ; Compare with current minimum
    jb   SetMin    ; Smaller, so record position
    jmp  Cont      ; Not smaller, so just continue
  Done:
    pop  bx
    ret
endp min
```

In the *swap* proc, if the position of the minimum is equal to the current front of the array, it's better to not swap elements at all.
And instead of using the stack and work with a single register `AL`, use extra registers like `CL` and `DL` for efficiency.

```
; IN () OUT () MOD (al,cl,dl)
proc swap
    push bx
    push si
    mov  bx, offset array
  More:
    call min       ; -> AL='$' SI
    cmp  si, bx
    je   Skip
    mov  cl, [bx]
    mov  dl, [si]
    mov  [bx], dl
    mov  [si], cl
  Skip:
    inc  bx
    cmp  [bx], al  ; AL='$'
    jne  More
    pop  si
    pop  bx
    ret 
endp swap
```

A drawback of using a terminator for working with your array is that the value 36 (ASCII code of the $-character) can not appear in the array itself.